# How to render a list in a webgrid column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

My model has as one of its properties, a list of objects. I use a webgrid on the view. Right now, my view model turns that list of objects into a string and my webgrid column displays the string. I've searched the Internet for examples of how to display a list in a webgrid column, but haven't come accross anything. I did find a blog that demonstrated how to use a webgrid inside a webgrid column, but that's not exactly what I was trying to do. I've tried this, but it generates an error (cannot convert from lambda to System.Func.

```
format: @<text>@foreach (var p in item.PhoneList) { p.PhoneNumber; }</text>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out how to do this myself.  Short Answer: You need an HTML Helper.  Here is a pretty [good reference on making your own](http://pratapreddypilaka.blogspot.com/2011/10/mvc-razor-custom-html-helper-calsses.html)

Basically you need to:

1. Make a Helpers/MyHelper.cs file
2. Make the MyHelper class static
3. Make a new function in the MyHelper class with the following signature:
   `public static MvcHtmlString MyFunction(this HtmlHelper helper, [input type] myInput)`

Then just add the appropriate references.  Call the Helper inline like this:

...

`MyWebGrid.Column(format: @<text>@Html.MyFunction(@item.[ListToExtract] as List<[ListTypeToExtract>)</text>, header:...`

...

Comment: Not really what I was hoping for, but I guess there's no way to accomplish what I was trying short of this. I think I'll just stick to creating the string in my ViewModel. I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a helper function in the view.

```
@helper WriteItems(List<string> myList)
{
    foreach (var myItem in myList)
    {
       <span>@myItem</span>
    }
}
```

Then call it from the webgrid column:

```
format: item => (WriteItems(item.Labels)
```